# How do I consider a space character in a trie?

Tags: java, dictionary, trie

For example, I want to insert "a few" in the trie, but I do not know how to do it:

```
public void insertWord(String wordName){
    for (int i = 0; i < wordName.length(); i++){
        if( current.children[wordName.charAt(i) - 'a'] == null)
            current.children[wordName.charAt(i) - 'a'] = new Node(wordName.charAt(i));
        current = current.children[wordName.charAt(i) - 'a'];
    }
}
```

I get this error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -65 out of bounds for length 29

The length of array is equal to 29.

How can I solve this?

Comment: You can *decide* to ignore it. Nothing in a trie treats any value special.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you define the index for the `children` array with the expression `wordName.charAt(i) - 'a'`. But the ordinal value of a space is much smaller than that of `'a'`, so that becomes a negative value.

Instead, you could define the conversion from character to index with the help of a constant string:

```
private static final String ALPHABET = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ";
```

Notice the space after the `z`. You could add more characters, if you want to support other characters like a comma, a point, ... capital letters, ...etc. **But**, the length of this string should not be greater than the length of the `children` array.

Then, in your function, you can use that string as follows:

```
    int key = ALPHABET.indexOf(wordName.charAt(i));
    if( current.children[key] == null)
        current.children[key] = new Node(wordName.charAt(i));
    current = current.children[key];
```